# Write the name of a parent file (.intent)

Tags: java, android

my question is
One of the top file, how do we write in intent?

```
   Intent i = new Intent(activities/splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

see:**activities/splashscreen.this**

Comment: It's hard to tell what's being asked here.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. This is just a guess. `Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class);`

Comment: no, this file will specify how it inside a folder?

Comment: The first parameter in this case, is a Context. It should be the Context of the Activity that is creating the Intent. Please read the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: You don't need to specify the folder. Android Studio will do all the necessary imports.

Comment: Is this code inside SplashScreen.java?

Comment: Yes, i dont understand.
Everything is a normal,but the program gives an error

Comment: Post your complete code. Not just two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my guess:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```